# What is the correct FSA representation of the following string sequence?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Based on [this](http://blog.burntsushi.net/transducers/#construction) article, i am trying to imagine how i would construct an FSA based index for the following string sequence:

1. ABCDEF
2. ABDDDF
3. ABDDEFGHI

These are the representations that i found:
[image: Representations]
There are problems with each:

The first introduces a new key in the automata that really isn't in the set (ABCDEFGHI)

The second one is the closest to my heart but it is more trie-like, so it can be inefficient at a large scale.

The third saves a lot of final states therefore saves some space. However, state 9 has multiple "F" transitions which i think is illegal.

So the big question is: Which one of the above is correct? If none of them, please share what is the correct!

Thank you

Comment: Where did you find them? You already seem to think that only 2 is correct; have you tried proving your claim? Are you aware that DFA can be minimized?

Comment: This example is mine. My problem is that none of the examples found in articles contain strings that are subsets of each other and i am curious about this case.
I am biased towards solution 2, because i think it is the correct but i cannot prove as i am not sure about the strict rules of minimization.

Comment: I also know from the article that general minimization is possible but it is a very slow operation. The mentioned article offers a more efficient solution but it doesn't make situations like this clear.

Comment: Minimization is fast; it's determinisation that can be slow. The trie of words would be a natural, already quite small, and deterministic starting point. Just run determinisation on it; there's no better general procedure, I suspect.

Comment: Ad 3: State 9 is fine -- you get an NFA, not a DFA. NFAs can be exponentially smaller than the smallest DFA, but are not as helpful for deriving (efficient) algorithms.

Comment: @Marcell, are you sure `ABDDEFGHI` can get accepted in any of these finite automata.I don't think so

Comment: Oh no! Sorry, mistyped the input strings. the correct one is ABDDDFGHI. The important part is that the second is a subset of the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think none of your finite automata accepts the third string `ABDDEFGHI`.The following is what I think a correct finite automaton for accepting all three strings

[image]

In case where your language has the third string `ABDDDFGHI`.The first is wrong since it accepts another string.The third also seems incorrect since there are multiple labels of same letter exiting from one node.Your second automaton is correct but you may want something like this

[image]

Comment: i overlooked that small optimization, thank you!

Comment: @Marcell , Always consider a common sink